# ¿Reiniciar o cerrar un programa ingresando una palabra en C?

Tags: c

tengo este código, el programa hace lo suyo y cuando termina indica que para continuar se ingrese el 0 o para cerrar cualquier otro numero, lo que quiero hacer es que para continuar se ingrese la palabra 'continuar' o seguir' y para cerrar la palabra 'salir'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//Funciones para Area

float areftcir(float r); //Area de un circulo

int main(void) {
    int resp = 0;
    float ra, res;

    while(resp == 0)
    {
        printf("\n\nIntrduzca el valor del radio: ");
        scanf("%f", &ra);
        res = areftcir(ra);
        printf("Respuesta: %f", res);

        printf("\n\nIngrese '0' para regresar: ");
        scanf("%d", &resp);    
    }
}

float areftcir(float r) {
    float raftc;
    raftc = (3.1416) * (r * r);
    return raftc;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una solución facil para ello, utiliza un array de `char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

//Funciones para Area

float areftcir(float r); //Area de un circulo

int main(void) {
    float ra, res;
    char cadena[10]; // Lo suficientemente grande como para aceptar "continuar"

    do {
        printf("\n\nIntrduzca el valor del radio: ");
        scanf("%f", &ra);
        res = areftcir(ra);
        printf("Respuesta: %f", res);

        printf("\n\nIngrese 'continuar' o 'salir': ");
        scanf("%s[^\n]", &cadena);    
    } while (strcmp(cadena, "continuar") == 0);
}

float areftcir(float r) {
    float raftc;
    raftc = (3.1416) * (r * r);
    return raftc;
}
```

Básicamente lo que hace es comparar si el contenido de `cadena` es equivalente a `"continuar"`.

El mayor problema de esto es que sólo funcionará si el usuario escribe `continuar` en minusculas, sin signos de puntuación ni nada y que va a ignorar cualquier otra palabra que introduzcas.

Adicionalmente, algo malo puede pasar si pasas de 10 caracteres.

He cambiado tu ciclo `while` con un `do { ... } while` para realizar las operaciones del programa por lo menos una vez.

**EDIT**:

Para volverlo más comodo al usuario, he hecho una pequeña mejora, que es la de ignorar el tipo de letra *(Mayúscula o Minúscula)*:

Primero, agregamos el prototipo de función:

```
char *str_tolower(char *ptr);
```

Y la definimos de la siguiente manera:

```
char *str_tolower(char *ptr) {
    char *test = ptr;
    while (ptr && *ptr) {
        *ptr = tolower(*ptr); ++ptr;
    }
    return test;
}
```

Luego sólo cambiamos la siguiente línea:

```
} while (strcmp(cadena, "continuar") == 0);
```

Por:

```
} while (strmp(str_tolower(cadena), "continuar") == 0);
```

Y ahora el usuario es capaz de escribir `"continuar"` de cualquier forma.

Comment: Increíble muchas gracias, me funciono :)

Answer (score 1):

Una respuesta *alternativa* a la del buen `Cloruro de Sodio` (demasiado *salada* para mi gusto ;-) ).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char resp[255] = { 0 };

  while( 1 ) {
    printf("\n\nIntrduzca el valor del radio, o [salir]: " );
    scanf("%s", resp);

    if( !strcmp( resp, "salir" ) )
      break; 

    printf("Respuesta: %f\n", areftcir( strtof( resp ) );
  }
}
```

`strtof( )` convierte una cadena a `float`.

`strcmp( )` compara cadenas. `== 0` sin sin iguales.

Comment: ¡Recuerda `#include <string.h>`! Ah, que me molestan los warnings de algunos compiladores, _*mira a `gcc` fijamente*_

Comment: @NaCl *Sorry*. La verdad es que no lo he probado, lo hice a la cabeza. No volverá a ocurrir :-)

Comment: La verdad es que ese warning solo lo tira gcc y es algo molesto :P